# How do you make a rollover menu?

Tags: javascript, html, css, rollover

I was wondering how to make a rollover menu like this http://wareztuga.ws/

Which language is it?

Can you give me the function/tutorial for that?

How hard can it be to make a rollover menu with that sort of design?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a pretty useful tutorial, http://www.webtoolkit.info/jquery-menu.html
Enjoy it!

Answer (score 2):

Its all css/javascipt. There are many libraries out there that help you with this.

Try [Superfish](http://users.tpg.com.au/j_birch/plugins/superfish/).

You will need to know, javascript, a little jquery and some html.

Have a look at the [examples](http://users.tpg.com.au/j_birch/plugins/superfish/#examples).

In terms of design, you need to change/work with, the CSS (superfish.css). Here you can change the colors, and graphics that are displayed.

Comment: I'm not trying to make a new portal like that website i'm trying to edit SMF header. Is it still possible with that code?

Comment: whats SMF? Its not for making a portal just a plian menu. Have you looked at the examples page?

Comment: http://www.simplemachines.org/ - At the moment i'm making a downloads website and I wanted to organize the menus like, Programs and then a redirect for programs forum. Are you understanding?

Comment: Well I don't know anything about this SMF/forum, but if you can edit the html for the header and add some javascript then I think it should be possible. See the examples on the superfish page and see if you can add that html/css/js into your forum.